# Disk is full and I cannot login to change it

Tags: login, disk

My disk was quiet full for a while now, but I had no time to delete files.

Today I installed an update which first was not possible, but the command line allowed it. After rebooting my computer I could not login anymore.

All tools I used reported that zero bytes of the root fs are available. However, when I delete files via a shell (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) nothing changes.

I use an encrypted home folder and `eCryptfs` heavily complains about the space.

I deleted some rather big files I don't need anymore by `rm -rf`. **Why does this not help?**

I'm a computer science student, but not really into the Ubuntu internals.

As requested the (important parts of the) output of `df -h`:

```
FS.      size    used   avail. usage
/dev/sda2 109G   104G  0       100%
```

(Exactly the same also for `/home/username/.Private`)

Comment: Whats `df -h` telling?

Comment: I added the important parts to my question. No other device is > 4MByte.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The system reserves space, which is explained here: [Unix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7950/reserved-space-for-root-on-a-filesystem-why)

So actually, you have to delete some more, in order to be able to write again without root permissions.

Comment: I'm now down to 88% and I can login again! Thank you!